# getting issue with gradle build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

The gradle build for the project was working fine a short while ago but now consistently failing with the error below (output with --info flag):

```
Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'. Working directory: /home/abc/git/xyz Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Djava.security.manager=jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -DsysProp=value -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -cp /home/abc/git/xyz/$PATH:/opt/abc/gradle-2.9/caches/2.9/workerMain/gradle-worker.jar jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 1'
Successfully started process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.InternalError: Could not create SecurityManager: jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.child.BootstrapSecurityManager
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:106)
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<clinit>(Launcher.java:57)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1448)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1433)

Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 2'. Working directory: /home/abc/git/xyz Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Djava.security.manager=jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -DsysProp=value -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -cp /home/abc/git/xyz/$PATH:/opt/abc/gradle-2.9/caches/2.9/workerMain/gradle-worker.jar jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 2'
Successfully started process 'Gradle Test Executor 2'
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.InternalError: Could not create SecurityManager: jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.child.BootstrapSecurityManager
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:106)
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<clinit>(Launcher.java:57)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1448)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1433)

Process 'Gradle Test Executor 2' finished with non-zero exit value 1
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 2' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultWorkerProcess.onProcessStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:91)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultWorkerProcess.access$000(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:35)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultWorkerProcess$1.executionFinished(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor302.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.executionFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:214)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.finished(DefaultExecHandle.java:312)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.completed(ExecHandleRunner.java:103)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea what might be causing the issue and how best to solve it?

Comment: running build with skip test (gradle build -x test at least gets the build process working)

Comment: are you setting any jvmArgs for your test task? Might be a similar problem to this: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/java-lang-internalerror-could-not-create-securitymanager-jarjar-org-gradle-process-internal-child-bootstrapsecuritymanager/2478/3

Comment: I took out the jvm arguments before posting here - that was not the reason.  I will update here once I can pinpoint what was causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was stemming from the unit tests (pilot error).  When I ran build with skip tests, the build process worked fine.  Obviously, the unit tests need to be fixed to fix this issue (as opposed to using the skip tests band aid).

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else that might run into this I resolved by doing the following:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle
rm -rf YOUR_PROJECT/.gradle
```

I first tried just `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches` but that wasn't enough.

Comment: The only thing to mention is if you have 
~/.gradle/gradle.properties file, do not remove it.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I also was just removing the ~/.gradle/caches folder. Removing moar gradle fixed this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try running "gradle --stop" before running your task

> gradle --stop

Answer (score 1):

The problem went away after deleting the gradle cache folder.
Remove the `.gradle/caches` folder and try.

Comment: To flaggers: This is an answer. Removing just the cache folder is not any of the other answers, so this stands alone as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error-

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.InternalError: Could not create SecurityManager: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager         at sun.misc.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:103)
```

The suggestion mentioned on [this GitHub issue #4689](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4689) helped me-

1. [Delete the Gradle cache](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4689#issuecomment-373233276) `<HOME>/.gradle/caches`
2. [Stop the Gradle daemon](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4689#issuecomment-426797854) `./gradlew --stop`
3. Now re-build the project `./gradlew build`